# Grafana Plugin - how to remove metric panel from react plugin

Tags: reactjs, plugins, grafana

I am new to Grafana and I am creating a plugin in react, with the help of `simple-react-plugin`.

I want to remove datasource/metrics query panel (only need panel editor).

I am just wondering **how to remove it**.

As per `simple-react-plugin` I had imported:

```
import { PanelPlugin } from ‘@grafana/data’;
```

I was trying to change it to:

```
import { PanelPlugin } from ‘@grafana/ui’;
```

but it is giving me the error:

> @grafana/ui module has no exported member ‘PanelPlugin’.

Anybody can please help me on this…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by adding a `"skipDataQuery": true` entry into `plugin.json`. This is how the built-in Text Panel does it.